# iPhone - calling a method in parent view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, macros, hierarchy

have hunted around for an answer to this one, but can't seem to find a definitive solution - hoping someone can help here!

I'm building a multiview app for the iPhone.  I've created a UIViewController called "MainViewController", which loads in other views as required.  There's quite a lot of navigation between screens, so what I'd like to do is have a "ViewSwitcher" method in MainViewController that the child view controllers can call to ask for the view to switch away to another child view.

How can I call the "ViewSwitcher" method from the child controllers?  I've managed to achieve this at present by creating an UIView *"parent" property in each child view controller, and populating this on first loading the child view.  I can then call the method using [parent ViewSwitcher].  This seems a bit clunky, and I'm concerned I'm creating some horribly recursive structure.  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that looks clunky, but it should demonstrate the general idea:

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;
[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex] setBackBarButtonItemTitle:@"New Title"];
```

Much of this can easily be replaced with a `#define` macro:

```
#define CurrentParentViewController [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] - 2]
```

You might then use it as follows:

```
[CurrentParentViewController setBackBarButtonItemTitle:@"New Title"];
```

This would obviously crash and burn if you call this at the bottom-most view controller in the navigation stack, but presumably you would know when you're using this approach. You could, for example, call `[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]` to make sure you can run this.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  If I understand this correctly, you'd put this in the child view and it would obtain *every* view controller that the parent controller had defined.

If I'm following this right - how do you know that it's offset by two?  Is it because the last entry will be (count-1) and will correspond to the current view and the penultimate one (count-2) will be its immediate owner?

Many thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Array indices are 0-based: Array[0] is the first element, Array[1] is the second element, etc. The index of the current view controller will be the (length-1) index of the `-viewControllers` array. The index of the current view controller's parent view controller will be at the (length-2) index of the `-viewControllers` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton object.  This [cocoawithlove article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) does a magnificent job on this topic.

Comment: Much appreciated - I've had a trawl through and it seems to make sense.  I was just getting concerned about setting up pointers to the parent view in every view structure!

Many thanks!